# Pywhatkit in proxy network

Tags: python

I am using Pywhatkit to send Whatsapp msg. It works in my home network without any problem But in my office we use proxy server for internet. In that network pywhatkit throws an error. How to use pywhatkit in proxy network?

The Error as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
self._prepare_proxy(conn)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _prepare_proxy
conn.connect()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 364, in connect
conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 501, in *connect_tls_proxy
socket = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be
HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'))))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\core\core.py", line 39, in check_connection
requests.get("https://google.com")
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'))))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Z.MyFiles\Programs\Dev\Python\msg.py", line 1, in 
import pywhatkit
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit_*init*_.py", line 16, in 
from pywhatkit.whats import (
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\whats.py", line 13, in 
core.check_connection()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\core\core.py", line 41, in check_connection
raise InternetException(
pywhatkit.core.exceptions.InternetException: Error while connecting to the Internet. Make sure you are connected to the Internet!

Comment: "*pywhatkit throws an error*" What is the exact error?